# How to filter models by currently authenticated user using ModelViewSet in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-filter, django-rest-viewsets

I'm working on Django project with Django Rest Framework. I have a model called `Server` and I want to filter the `queryset` by the currently authenticated user, but only if "by_user=true" is provided in query params. I'm using `ModelViewSet` to create the API endpoints. I have overrided the `get_queryset` and it works fine. But when I return is using `super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)` it returns the queryset without filtering. Only way I found to return the filtered queryset is by using `Response(serializer.data)`. But I want to use the `super().list()` method. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is `Server Model`:

```
class Server(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)
    owner = ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="server_owner"
    )
    category = ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="server_category")
    description = CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    members = ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="server_members", blank=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here's `Serializer`:

```
class ServerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = "__all__"
```

And Here's `ViewSet`:

```
class ServerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Server.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ServerFilter

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        by_user = request.query_params.get("by_user", False)
        if by_user:
            queryset = queryset.filter(members=request.user)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
        # return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `super()` keyword is used to call methods and attributes from the inherited/parent class, in your case `ModelViewset`.

Returning `super().list()` will call the `.list()` method defined in the `ModelViewset` class and not the one you have defined in your `ServerViewSet` class.

Remember the `.list()` method in the `ModelViewset` class does not filter the data and that is why you have overridden it in your `ServerViewset` class so that you can have the data filtered.
So you only have to return your filtered data or queryset using `return Response(serializer.data)`.

There is no need to use `super().list()` in your case.